# Java Byte Code Debugger

Tags: java

I'm trying to reverse a highly obfuscated program written in java.  None of the deobfuscators seem to work so I have been poking at it in eclipse.  I can attach to a running process and have figured some of the code out but it appears the part im after happens in a synthetic function so I want to be able to step line by line through the byte code and see whats going on.  None of the tools I have found so far seem to have this ability.  I appreciate any suggestions.

What I've tried
1.) Eclipse with various plugins (can kind of decompile code but without line numbers its little help debugging)
2.) Recaf(useful for static analysis but have not found a way to use it in a debug fashion)
3.) Several deobfuscators with no luck

Comment: You can pretty easily write a basic transformer to strip the synthetic flag from methods if Eclipse is skipping over those. I've had *some* success with similar setups but using IntelliJ.